# How can I prevent a table from repeating in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a SSRS report with two tables. One is built from the SQL code and made up of expressions - it's basically a report card that creates a new row for each subject that the student studies.

Below that, I have created another table which only has text, and is in no way utilizing the SQL dataset. However, for every row created by the first table, the second table is duplicated. For example, if the student has 7 subjects, then the second table will be repeated 7 times. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Did you place the hardcoded table inside your table generated by dataset?

Comment: Do you mean did I place it inside a cell of that table? In that case, no. They are two separate tables.

Comment: Did you happen to assign the second table to your dataset? If so, try removing the dataset in the table properties.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest option is to use textbox instead of table if you are only using that table as a text area but if you don't want to use a textbox just delete the details group that gets set up by default during creation of table. http://prntscr.com/8wy2by. So that leaves the header only and it will not repeat. If you want to add more row you could right click on the left side of that header and select insert row. See this image http://prntscr.com/8wy2lc.

I hope you get the point. :)

Comment: That was the issue, the data row repeats, delete it and and add a row to replace what was there and no repeating.